# Need to run 'read' command in C code

Tags: c, linux, bash

I need to run the following bash command in my c code:

`read -rsp $'Press spacebar to continue...\n' -d $' '`

basically I need to pause at a certain point and have the user hit spacebar to continue. I can't use getchar() or anything from standard library...

I'm trying to use the execl command but can't seem to get it formated correctly.

Perhaps there's another way to do this...

Comment: How about [`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) ?

Comment: system says the following: 'read: Illegal option -s'

Comment: Then the problem is not on the C side. Does `man 1 read` report the existence of the `-s` flag on your system ?

Comment: im not sure? `man 1 read` says No manual entry for read in section 1

Comment: My system works ok with `read -rsp ...`. You all must be Zombies or FaceShrug users.

Comment: my system works fine if i type it directly into bash but thats not the problem...

Comment: Why can't you use `getchar()` or anything from the standard library? Apparently you can use `execl`, which is part of the POSIX standard library but not part of the C standard library. Can you state your requirements more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

add header, `#include <stdlib.h>`

and use ths `system("<Command to pass to system>");`
for both windows and linux system, you can use the function and entire commandline along with pipeline , redirections etc also can be used.

to pause the system use `pause` command as argument for `system()` for windows

put the commands in a shell script and invoke the shell script using `system` function.

Comment: The OP is using Linux, not Windows.

Comment: @Keith Thompson ya, just a related solution for other platform also, since the answer was with a standard library function.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the `system()` function passes its argument to `/bin/sh` to be executed. `/bin/sh` may or may not be the same shell as `/bin/bash`. You'll need to invoke `bash` explicitly to be sure that all those options to `read` are supported.

To do that from a shell prompt, you can type `bash -c ...`, where `...` is a single string containing a command to be executed:

```
bash -c "read -rsp $'Press spacebar to continue...\n' -d $' '"
```

Now you need to pass that entire command line as a string to the `system()` function. To do that, you need to enclose it in double quotes *and* escape any double quotes or backslashes within it:

```
system("bash -c \"read -rsp $'Press spacebar to continue...\\n' -d $' '\"");
```